# Output string data of HttpQueryInfoW

Tags: c++, winapi, http, wininet

Does HttpQueryInfoW output ANSI or UNICODE strings in the following cases?

HTTP_QUERY_SET_COOKIE
HTTP_QUERY_ACCEPT_RANGES
HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_RANGE
HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_DISPOSITION
HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF
HTTP_QUERY_LOCATION
HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH
HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_TYPE

Thanks

Comment: With 17 questions and 0 accepted answers, I think it's time to start looking through your "SO attic" for long lost questions you never accepted.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpQueryInfoW` is the Unicode version of `HttpQueryInfo` so it always returns Unicode.

Unicode and ANSI names:

- `HttpQueryInfoW` (Unicode)
- `HttpQueryInfoA` (ANSI)

`HttpQueryInfo` is available in Microsoft Internet Explorer 3.0 for the ANSI character set and in Internet Explorer 4.0 or later for ANSI and Unicode characters.